# How to add papsersize to microsoft XPS document Writer by modify .gpd file

Tags: xpsdocument, v4-printer-driver

I wish to add a new papersize named 'ABC'

I Add in mxdwdui.gpd file as follows

*Option: ABC
{
*rcName: =258
*OptionID: 258
*PageDemenssion: PAIR(10000, 10000)
*PrintableArea: PAIR(9900, 9900)
*PrintableOrigin: PAIR(50, 50)
}

It meet the Requirements of document
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/supporting-vendor-defined-paper-sizes

But I can not open Printer preferences if I Add it

Anyone knows how to make it?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `"*PageDimensions"` instead of `"*PageDemenssion"`.  I would also recommend `"*Name"` instead of `"*rcName"`.  The following should work:

```
*Option: ABC
{
    *Name: "ABC"
    *PageDimensions: PAIR(10000,10000)
    *switch: Orientation
    {
        *case: PORTRAIT
        {
            *PrintableArea: PAIR(9900,9900)
            *PrintableOrigin: PAIR(50, 50)
            *CursorOrigin: PAIR(50, 50)
        }
        *case: LANDSCAPE_CC270
        {
            *PrintableArea: PAIR(9900,9900)
            *PrintableOrigin: PAIR(50, 50)
            *CursorOrigin: PAIR(50, 50)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I can open printer preferences after add contents above, BUT it did not show in papersize drop list of XPS printer, is there any more contents need to be added?

Comment: Have you restarted the Print Spooler service, or restarted your PC?  The changes may not be loaded until the Print Spooler is restarted.

Comment: I restarted PC, but the papersize 'ABC' is still missing. Does it have any relevance with the property [*Option: CUSTOMSIZE]?